# Do Apex collections implement iterable?

Tags: apex, collection

Do Apex collection classes implement Iterable interface? I want to write a generic function that can take any of the collection classes that support foreach. Is this possible?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `List<ANY>` class implements `Iterable<ANY>`, but neither `Map<ANY, ANY>` nor `Set<ANY>` does.

Try the following code in v30:

```
System.debug((new set<id>()) instanceOf Iterable<Object>);
System.debug((new list<id>()) instanceOf Iterable<Object>);
System.debug((new map<id, object>()) instanceOf Iterable<Object>);
System.debug((new set<id>()) instanceOf Iterator<Object>);
System.debug((new list<id>()) instanceOf Iterator<Object>);
System.debug((new map<id, object>()) instanceOf Iterator<Object>);
```

Output:

```
12:30:33.073 (73681264)|USER_DEBUG|[1]|DEBUG|false
12:30:33.073 (73971363)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|DEBUG|true
12:30:33.074 (74136981)|USER_DEBUG|[3]|DEBUG|false
12:30:33.074 (74346453)|USER_DEBUG|[4]|DEBUG|false
12:30:33.074 (74526971)|USER_DEBUG|[5]|DEBUG|false
12:30:33.074 (74793803)|USER_DEBUG|[6]|DEBUG|false
```

So, in short, you need to handle each individually.

Comment: `Set` is gaining the `Iterable` interface in Summer '23.

Comment: @JasonClark Yes, I was aware of that, it's sometimes hard to track down which of the 13k answers I have that need updating. I appreciate you bringing this post to my attention. Also, I found an apparent bug to report with the new release, which I'm working on reporting.

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't meant as a criticism - I appreciate all of your great answers.  I considered editing the answer, but I dislike editing other folks answers aside from formatting fixes, and it's not GA yet besides.  I came across this answer while researching another `Iterable` issue (`public ClassName(Iterable<A>){}` and `public ClassName(Iterable<B>)` are treated as the same by the compiler), and commented for reference for the next person who reads it.

Answer (score 5):

`List` and `Set` not both being directly iterable via something like a common `Collection` interface is frustrating.

Not sure when it was introduced and it is not documented but `Set` does have an `iterator` method so you could write methods that take an `Iterator` but that is fairly ugly:

```
@isTest
private class A {
    @isTest
    static void iterateList() {
        System.assertEquals(1 + 2 + 3, sum(new List<Integer>{1, 2, 3}.iterator()));
    }
    @isTest
    static void iterateSet() {
        System.assertEquals(4 + 5, sum(new Set<Integer>{4, 5, 5}.iterator()));
    }
    private static Integer sum(Iterator<Integer> iter) {
        Integer sum = 0;
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            sum += iter.next();
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Writing methods that accept a `List` and wrapping sets in lists is what I have been doing:

```
@isTest
private class B {
    @isTest
    static void iterateList() {
        System.assertEquals(1 + 2 + 3, sum(new List<Integer>{1, 2, 3}));
    }
    @isTest
    static void iterateSet() {
        System.assertEquals(4 + 5, sum(new List<Integer>(new Set<Integer>{4, 5, 5})));
    }
    private static Integer sum(List<Integer> l) {
        Integer sum = 0;
        for (Integer i : l) {
            sum += i;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

(Don't think `Map` really belongs directly in this discussion.)

Comment: see http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/143417/2602 for the one instance where documented for sets.

Answer (score 2):

No, to my knowledge there is no way to use same code to iterate over Lists, Sets and Maps. You would have to provide 3 different entry points for your logic (override methods with different parameters perhaps) and wrap the rest in a function.

Additionally, you won't be able to reuse your code for anything other than sObjects or your custom object hierarchy since Salesforce doesn't support parametrised interfaces after api v26.0 (see comments to the answer of [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1214/can-you-use-generics-in-apex))

Comment: Lists do indeed implement `Iterable<ANY>` (see my answer), but Sets and Maps do not. [I posted an idea on the IdeaExchange](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kxLyAAI) about this, since it directly affects the ability to use things like `String.join(Iterable<ANY>, String)`.