# Batch to batch call for inserting large data

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex

```
 public someClass{
    public static someMethod(){
      //this method is called in some batch
        list<sObject> slist= new list<sObject>();
       //some operation
       //slist size is 50000 need to be inserted 
      Util.insertHelper(slist);
   }
}

 //method in Util class
 public static insertHelper(list<sObject> slist){
   SoListBatch slb= new SoListBatch(slist);
   Database.executeBatch(slb,199);
 }




global with sharing class SoListBatch implements    Database.Batchable<Sobject>,Database.Stateful{

global list<sObject> accList;
global SoListBatch(list<sObject>al){
    accList=al;
}

global Iterable<sObject> start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    //return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    return accList;
}
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope){
    insert scope;
}
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){

  }

}
```

Note:-

1)Whether this will work or not?

2)Is this approach  the only way or there any other work around ??

Comment: salesforce still doesn't permit to call a database.executeBatch call from another database.executeBatch.

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfectly legitimate approach, and is probably ideal when speaking of 50,000 rows that need to be updated at once. You'd get slightly better performance by leaving the batch size at 200 instead of 199 (that's the size of a trigger batch).

Comment: This approach is not feasible.

Comment: @Asitm9 You can call database.executebatch only in the "finish" method; using this technique, you can chain batches together.

Comment: I just attempted implement a similar batch class, using an object list as an iterable. But when I ran a test unit on it, I got the error:  " No more than one executeBatch can be called from within a testmethod. Please make sure the iterable returned from your start method matches the batch size, resulting in one executeBatch invocation."

Comment: For test methods, you have to not chain the batch: `if(!Test.isRunningTest()) ...`. You'll need to use a test-visible variable within the class if you want to simulate chaining and thus achieve 100% coverage.

Comment: Yup, you're right, though that wasn't what caused my issue in the end (it was because I thought I could test inserting more than 10k rows, but test code only allows one instance of a batch execute method, so I just coded the test to insert 200 rows and trusted it to work on larger sets)

Comment: SFDCFox, you mention chaining using the 'finish' method of the batch, and I do know what you're referring to, but I'm confused why you bring it up here, since the OPs code doesn't do that - he just iterates through his >10k record list.

Answer (score -1):

Your code won't compile because Batch `start()` method supposed to return object implementing `Iterable<sObject>` interface, but you are returning List which doesn't implement this interface.

Below is code I used in same situation to get around this limitation:

```
global with sharing class SomeBatchClass implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {

    List<sObject> objectList;

    public SomeBatchClass(List<sObject> l) {
        objectList = l;
    }

    global Iterable<sObject> start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        return new CustomIterable(objectList);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope) {
        ...
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        ...
    }



    global class CustomIterable implements Iterable<sObject> {

        List<sObject> innerClassObjectList;

        public CustomIterable(List<sObject> l) {
            innerClassObjectList = l;
        }

        global Iterator<sObject> Iterator() {
            return innerClassObjectList.iterator();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Lists are Iterable, [see this](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/34087/do-apex-collections-implement-iterable/34122#34122).

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks, good to know that. I wish Apex documentation was clearer on which classes implement which interfaces.

Comment: I wish all classes that *should* implement an interface would...