# Doesn't Set<T> collection implement Iterable<T> interface?

Tags: apex, list, set, collection, interface

I am trying to join `String` elements of `Set` with semicolon.

```
Set<String> elements = new Set<String>{
    'foo',
    'bar'
    };
System.debug(String.join(elements, ';'));
```

getting the following exception

> Argument must implement Iterable

Is it weird, as we can easily iterate `Set` with foreach loop

```
for(String element :elements){
    System.debug(element);
}
```

It means, that `Set<T>` implements `Iterable<T>`, doesn't it?
From [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_join) about `String.join` method:

> Joins the elements of the specified iterable object, such as a List,
>   into a single String separated by the specified separator. Signature

However, `String.join` with `List` collection works good.

```
System.debug(String.join(new List<String>(elements), ';'));
```

> DEBUG|foo;bar

So do you have idea, why is it happening?

Comment: Please, upvote this idea -- https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kxLyAAI

Comment: Possible duplicate:
 [Do Apex collections implement iterable?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/34087/2995)

Answer (score 5):

Looks like Set does not implement iterable.

Code:

```
System.debug(new List<Object>() instanceof Iterable<Object>);
```

Output: `Compile failure on line 2, column 14: Operation instanceof is always true since an instance of List<Object> is always an instance of Iterable<Object>`

---

Code:

```
System.debug(new Set<Object>() instanceof Iterable<Object>);
```

Output: `11:38:23.10 (10761093)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|DEBUG|false`

Comment: looks like this. How is it possible to use foreach loop for Set then ? Weird

Comment: Looks like this is a feature of Apex language, foreach 
works with List or Set https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_loops_for_lists.htm