# How to use Set<ANY> with String.join(iterableObj, separator)?

Tags: apex

I was curious about using `Set<ANY>` in the [String.join(iterableObj, separator)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) method. When I try this code:

```
Set<String> mySet = new Set<String>();
mySet.add('One');
mySet.add('Two');
mySet.add('Three');
System.debug('mySet= ' + mySet);

String mySet_Joined_Exception = String.join(mySet, ', ');
System.debug('mySet_Joined_Exception= ' + mySet_Joined);
```

It fails to compile pointing to the line `String mySet_Joined_Exception = String.join(mySet, ', ');` with the following error:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void join(Set,
>   String) from the type String

Which means that it's not possible to use directly `Set<ANY>` with the String.join() method. This happens because `Set<ANY>` does not implement Iterable interface, which clearly explained in another post ["Do Apex collections implement iterable?"](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/34087/do-apex-collections-implement-iterable).

Nevertheless, what are the workarounds to this issue?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are quite a few options to solve this problem.

First, there is an idea [Apex Code: Implement `Iterable<T>` on `Set<T>`.](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kxLyAAI), which when implemented would eliminate the need for the below workarounds.

**Example on `Set<String>`**

```
Set<String> mySet = new Set<String>();
mySet.add('One');
mySet.add('Two');
mySet.add('Three');
System.debug('mySet= ' + mySet);
```

Debug:

```
08:53:25.1 (2682641)|USER_DEBUG|[5]|DEBUG|mySet= {One, Three, Two}
```

**Option 1 - cast it to `Iterable<T>`**

```
String mySet_Joined = String.join((Iterable<String>)mySet, ', ');
System.debug('mySet_Joined= ' + mySet_Joined);
```

Result:

```
08:53:25.1 (2944980)|USER_DEBUG|[8]|DEBUG|mySet_Joined= One, Two, Three
```

**UPDATE re- Option 1** - see this [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/226838/36878) for more info about why `(Iterable<String>)mySet` should not be used.

**Option 2 - convert original Set into List**

```
String mySet_Joined_List = String.join(new List<String>(mySet), ', ');
System.debug('mySet_Joined_List= ' + mySet_Joined_List);
```

Result:

```
08:57:13.1 (2812911)|USER_DEBUG|[11]|DEBUG|mySet_Joined_List= One, Two, Three
```

Comment: I went to go upvote that idea only to find that I had already upvoted it.

Comment: @DerekF I went to go upvote that idea only to find that I was the one that created it.

Answer (score 3):

In the Summer '23 release, the Iterable interface was implemented on the Set data structure. You can find more information about this implementation in the following resources:

Idea: [link](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdX2vUAF/apex-code-implement-iterable-on-set)

Release notes: [link](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=release-notes.rn_apex_set_implements_iterable.htm&release=244&type=5)

To make use of this feature, you simply need to update the API version of your Apex class to 58 or higher and then the code posted in the question will work as expected.

Comment: and it only took 10 years for Salesforce to deliver!

Comment: Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution for this is to use **toString** method as given below -

```
Set<String> mySet = new Set<String>();
mySet.add('One');
mySet.add('Two');
mySet.add('Three');
System.debug('mySet= ' + mySet);

String mySet_Joined_Exception = mySet.toString();
System.debug('mySet_Joined_Exception= ' + mySet_Joined); // output = {One, Two, Three}
```

You can remove the curly braces using the **remove()** method or you can use the **substring(startIndex, endIndex)** method of the String class.

Here, the only concern is the separator but that can be replaced by replace method.