# Are generics supported in developer console?

Tags: apex, developer-console

Reading [Can you use generics in Apex?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1214/can-you-use-generics-in-apex) generics are supported in apex. When I attempt to run the below trigger in developer console:

```
trigger TotalTriggerAccount on Account (after update) {
 
    System.debug('Updating account');
    
    String accountId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');

    List<Contact> allContacts = [
      SELECT
        *
      FROM
        Contact
      WHERE
        AccountId = :accountId
    ];
    
    for (Contact contact : allContacts) {
      System.debug(contact.Phone);
    }
    
}
```

to access all contacts for a given account I receive multiple Problems related to the use of generics and the declaration of the array such as:

```
Unexpected token '<'.
Unexpected token '>'.
Unexpected token ']'.
```

Is there a stop required in order to use generics and array elements in apex for developer console ?

Update:

By developer console, I refer to:

[image]

To add a new trigger from the developer console:

[image]

Comment: You're using some odd terminology (well, odd as in it's not really used in Apex or the documentation or community). Lists, Sets, and Maps are _collections_ (or collection types). About the only thing I see wrong here is your `SELECT *`. Apex/SOQL doesn't allow wildcard field definition. You need to specify each and every field you want to pull. I'd suggest going through some developer-focused modules on https://trailhead.salesforce.com to help you get your bearings in Apex.

Comment: Also, you probably aren't going to get any value from `ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');` inside of a trigger (fetching page parameters is typically used when you're writing a controller or controller extension for a Visualforce page). This is turning into an X-Y problem, I think.

Comment: @DerekF thanks, generics are used in multiple answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49220818/get-contact-emails-of-currently-active-account-as-list , does this question not show generics are avialable in apex with salesforce ?

Comment: My point is that they're not called "generics" on the Salesforce platform. It's a term you've picked up from elsewhere/another programming language. It'd be like talking about "templates" in Java. Most people could probably figure out that you really mean "generics", but the harder you make people work to understand your problem, the fewer people are going to bother trying to answer your questions.

Comment: Again, I suggest going through at least a few modules on https://trailhead.salesforce.com to get your bearings. [The Apex Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dev_guide.htm) is another option if you find trailhead too hand-holdy.

Comment: Also also, when you say "developer console", do you mean an anonymous apex window (debug -> open execute anonymous window) , or are you going to file -> new -> apex trigger to create a new trigger?

Comment: @DerekF I'm 'going to file -> new -> apex trigger to create a new trigger', please see question update for clarification.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot define a trigger in Execute Anonymous, which is what causes the other compilation errors. You are generally allowed to use [parameterized typing](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_parameterized_types.htm) in Execute Anonymous and code units (classes and triggers).

Also, you may be receiving errors because of the `*` in your field list. SOQL does not support the "all fields" operator found in SQL; you must explicitly list each field you want to retrieve. Because SOQL does not explicitly support this wildcard, it often causes unrelated compilation errors, such as the ones you've mentioned. In fact, writing invalid SOQL almost always causes unrelated compilation errors.